# Error on Oracle : ORA-29541

Tags: java, oracle, bash

I'm trying to call a bash script within a oracle database through a java script. To test it I just tried a basic script :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "It works !"
```

And the java script that I use is :

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class UAM_TOOLS{

    public static String Toto ()  throws IOException {
    String[] unixCommand = {"/home/oz380/toto.sh"};
    String pwd;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(unixCommand);
    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    pwd = input.readLine();
    input.close();
    return pwd;
    }
};
```

I granted all the permissions that had to be granted and I created the function in my database :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TOPI RETURN VARCHAR2
  2  as language java
  3  name 'UAM_TOOLS.Toto() return java.lang.String';
  4  /
```

But then when I call the function :

```
select TOPI from dual;
```

or :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2  G VARCHAR2(50);
  3  BEGIN
  4  G := UAM.TOPI;
  5  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(G);
  6  END;
  7  /
```

It doesn't work and prints the error :

```
ORA-29541: class UAM.UAM_TOOLS could not be resolved
```

I don't really understand what the problem can be. If anyone does I would be really thankful.

Comment: Do your PL/SQL function and the java object belong to the same user? Have you tried a simple Java routine that doesn't try to launch external processes?

Comment: The function and the java object do belong to the same user.
In fact I have to launch external processes. This script will be used to grant or delete profiles to users. To do so, several external processes have already been written. These are the scripts I will have to call.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you running? Can you compile and call a simple Java method (that doesn't use the file system, external processes etc)?

Comment: Also, what *exact* permissions did you grant?

Answer (score 0):

Before the

> CREATE FUNCTION

step you need to compile your class at command line

```
$>javac UAM_TOOLS.java
```

or using an IDE sth like Eclipse

that will generate compiled class with .class extension. For your case it will be UAM_TOOLS.class

And you still need to upload it to database on command line where the host which db runs on it

```
$>loadjava -user yourUserName/youPass@Yourdb UAM_TOOLS.class
```

after that 2 step you can resume with create function step.